# function for parameter for component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, components

How can I say that my angular2 component can receive a function as a parameter?

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'click' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'input'. ("   minlength="{{minlength}}"
>
> [ERROR ->]click="{{click}}"
>
> > "): ng:///AppModule/InputTextComponent.html@12:2

ComponentInput.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-text',
  templateUrl: './input-text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-text.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class InputTextComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() name: string;

  @Output() click = new EventEmitter();  

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Template Input Component:

```
    <input 
  type="text" 
  id="{{id}}" 
  name="{{name}}" 
  click="{{click}}"
  >
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  clique() {
    console.log('Clicando...')
  }
}
```

Componente.html

```
<app-input-text 
      id="2" 
      name="nome" 
      (click)="clique(event)"
      ngDefaultControl>

    </app-input-text>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgu4qn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't.

Let's take ngModel as the example : when you write

```
[(ngModel)]="x"
```

You have actually 3 distinct cases :

- `ngModel` is a built-in directive attribute, if used "naked" you **send a string to the tag**
- `[ngModel]` is an Input, meaning **you send data to the tag**
- `(ngModel)` is an Output, meaning **the tag is sending data to you**

What happens in your case is that you want to **send a string to your input**, but **the input isn't configured to accept Inputs**.

BUT, the input is configured to accept **event outputs**, such as clicks. In order to make it work, you have to write it like this

```
<input (click)="clique()">
```

I hope it is clear enough, if not, feel free to ask !

**EDIT** you can also write your input like so

```
<input [id]="id" [name]="name" (click)="clique($event)">
```

Comment: (click)="clique($event)". it worked for me, but in this case it should always be a function called 'click', I wanted any other name

Comment: Well you can't have another name. That's bound to the `onclick` event, it would not be wise to name it otherwise.